# Intel Euclid battery state

Tags: ros, battery

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I'm currently evaluating the Intel Euclid platform and I'm trying to find a solution to get battery state.

Any ideas or suggestions

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269683/intel-euclid-battery-state/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ rostopic echo /hardware_status
cs_name: EUCLID_7187
battery: 99
batteryStatus: Full

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2017-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-03**:
It looks like this might be published by https://github.com/IntelEuclid/euclid_system_monitor